# Transferring variable into a shell function

Tags: bash, unix

Is there a way to use shell function that accepts variable from the bash script (or rather, transfer a variable into a shell function)?

The following procedure works just fine (Note, I'm using this procedure as part of my need to implement output redirection as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609898/output-redirection-inside-bsub-command/50610765#50610765)):

```
mycmd() { cat <(head -3 MyProgrammingBook.txt|awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print "Helloworld",$0}') > outputfile.txt; }; 
export -f mycmd; 
bsub -q short "bash -c mycmd"
```

However, I would like to provide the initial file name as a variable and not as hardcoded name, something such as the following, but the following doesn't work:

```
myinputfile="MyProgrammingBook.txt";
mycmd() { cat <(head -3 ${myinputfile}|awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print "Helloworld",$0}') > outputfile.txt; }; 
export -f mycmd; 
bsub -q short "bash -c mycmd"
```

Ultimately, mycmd() would be called inside a loop and will be utilized each time with a different variable.

Comment: foo=123 bash -c 'echo $foo'

Comment: That's right, but how you make the function mycmd() to receive this variable? the function it self has to be able and recognize a variable...

Comment: `mycmd='cat <(head -3 ${myinputfile}|awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print "Helloworld",$0}') > outputfile.txt'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export` the variable too:

```
myinputfile="MyProgrammingBook.txt";
mycmd() { cat <(head -3 ${myinputfile}|awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print "Helloworld",$0}') > outputfile.txt; }; 
export -f mycmd;
export myinputfile;   # Here
bsub -q short "bash -c mycmd"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 'that other guy'!